# Swagger - how to get multiple operations with same http method and path but different content-type?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

as in the topic. I want to have different operations in swagger with same path and http method but with different content-type. Example:
I'm currently using Spring Boot in version 2.0.5  and Swagger ui in version 2.9.2.
In my API I have two methods to register user:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/customer+json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Registers a new application customer", notes = "Registers a new application customer.\n", response = CustomerResource.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Customer successfully registered"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "User with such email is already registered"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Customer registration request contains validation errors. Response contains detailed field validation error message"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 428, message = "Database error. Application log needs to be checked")})
public ResponseEntity<UserResource> registerCustomer(
        @ApiParam(value = "Model representation of the transferred data to register a new customer")  @Valid @RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto,
        UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder,  BindingResult bindingResult)
{
...
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes  = "application/partner+json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Registers a new application partner", notes = "Registers a new Easy Parking partner.\n", response = PartnerResource.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Partner successfully registered"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "User with such email is already registered"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Partner registration request contains validation errors. Response contains detailed field validation error message"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 428, message = "Database error. Application log needs to be checked")})
public ResponseEntity<UserResource> registerPartner(
        @ApiParam(value = "Model representation of the transferred data to register a new user")  @Valid @RequestBody PartnerDto partnerDto,
        UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, BindingResult bindingResult)
{ ... }
```

I want to have one POST path: /api/users to register two types of user: customer and partner. Two operations are required because partner has slightly different attributes than customer. I want to use content-type (consumes) to have different operations but swagger seems to work only with path and http method. Isn't it a bug?? Is there a way to configure it in Spring Boot Swagger?

Comment: I think you'll need a single method and use Swagger Core 2.x annotations, specifically [`@Content`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#content) - [here's an example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2573#issuecomment-350296673). The last link also says that annotating different methods with the same HTTP path+verb is currently not supported but planned for the future.